# Django Rest Framework custom permission not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, django-permissions, django-rest-viewsets

I want users to have access only to the records that belong to them, not to any other users' records so
I've created the following `view`:

```
class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwner]
    queryset = Address.objects.all()

    def retrieve(self, request, pk):
        address = self.address_service.get_by_id(pk)
        serializer = AddressSerializer(address)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I want only the owner of the records to have access to all the methods in this view ie retrieve, list, etc (I'll implement the remaining methods later) so I created the following `permissions.py` file in my `core` app:

```
class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        print('here in has_object_permission...')
        return obj.user == request.user
```

this wasn't working, so after going through stackoverflow answers I found this one [Django Rest Framework owner permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38718454/django-rest-framework-owner-permissions) where it indicates that `has_permission` method must be implemented. But as you can see in that answer, it's trying to get the `id` from the `view.kwargs` but my `view.kwargs` contains only the `pk` and not the user. How can I fix this? Do I need to implicitly pass the user id in the request url? that doesn't sound right.

Here's the test I'm using to verify a user cannot access other user's records:

```
def test_when_a_user_tries_to_access_another_users_address_then_an_error_is_returned(self):
        user2 = UserFactory.create()
        addresses = AddressFactory.create_batch(3, user=user2)
        address_ids = [address.id for address in addresses]
        random_address_id = random.choice(address_ids)

        url = reverse(self.ADDRESSES_DETAIL_URL, args=(random_address_id,))

        res = self.client.get(url, format='json')

        print(res.data)
```

Currently just using the test to check the data returned, will implement the assertions later on.

**Edit**

So I added `has_permission` method to `IsOwner`:

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_authenticated
```

if I put a print statement here it gets printed, but doesn't seem to be hitting the `has_object_permission` method, none of the prints I added there are being displayed

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783568/10052161) was the right one for me.

It says:

> The has_object_permission is not called for list views. The
> documentation says the following:
>
> Also note that the generic views will only check the object-level permissions for views that retrieve a single model instance. If you
> require object-level filtering of list views, you'll need to filter
> the queryset separately. See the filtering documentation for more
> details.

[Link to documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

Answer (score 0):

Note: The instance-level **has_object_permission** method will only be called if the view-level **has_permission** checks have already passed.

You need to write the **has_permission** too in order to make your custom permission works.

[Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) is the official docs and mentioned it. It should works after you add in **has_permission**.

Comment: in my edit you can see that I added it, yet `has_object_permission` is never invoked. By adding `print` statements in both methods I can see that `has_permission` is invoked but `has_object_permission` is not

Comment: show me your full permissions code if can

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions), permissions are checked on `self.get_object` method call.

```
def get_object(self):
    obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj
```

Which basically is all `retrieve` method does in `ModelViewSet`

```
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Whatever it is you do in `self.address_service.get_by_id(pk)` should either be moved to `self.get_object` or call `self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)` in `retrieve` method.

In the basic scenario this is all you need. There's no need to overwrite `retrieve` method.

```
class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwner]
    queryset = Address.objects.all()
```